# Is it possible to detect gender using firebase ML kit

Tags: android, firebase, google-mlkit

Is it possible to detect gender using firebase ML kit , if possible give me some some suggestion and resources

Comment: Remember that people of different genders may not look like you expect.  Trying to classify people's gender by looking at them is, [as this answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62744949/208273), going to be an uphill battle, and you'll make mistakes that will make your app look bad.  I'd really suggest not trying to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Google ML Kit (it was recently separated from Firebase) does not have an ML model that classifies pictures according to the gender of subject(s) in that picture. If you want something like that, you'll have to [train your own ML model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/train-image-labeler).

Personal note: I expect that any such model will be highly unreliable or subject to biases in the data used to train it.

Comment: how can i learn , i tried to use microsoft azure , but its pain, and google vision, i coundnt properly, any other third party api or anything else just give me proper guidlines

Comment: I have no recommendations there (and they'd be off topic here anyway), but this has some promising results: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+train+my+own+model+to+classify+images Within Firebase I've been meaning to look at Auto ML, but haven't found the time yet: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/train-image-labeler